# Angular js ng-show and ng-hide with animation using toggle class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help how to use animation ng-hide and ng-show. for Toggle class.

I have one div default it should be hide when i click the button it will show from left to right with animation and when i click same button it will go to right to left.

I need animation for this one. Please any one help me out this one

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am posting a link. That will help you for sure.

Comment: Hi @ved, Can you please post the link !thanks

Comment: I have updated answer. If you find it working inform.

Comment: I am trying to do using toggle class

$scope.toggle = function(){
   $scope.animate = !$scope.animate;

}

my problem is when set hide that time animation is not working.

Comment: It if fine for when left to right, But right to left animation is not working properly. Can please help me any one !thanks

Comment: Can you post your code.?

Answer (score 0):

Extending my comment:

This a link where you can find your answer.

```
   Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/uuwuZWoFsm4AOOaOOh9B?p=preview
```

For documentation details Visit: `http://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angular-apps-ngshow-and-nghide`

Hope It will work for you.